# How to resolve "import/no-unresolved" in ESLint for import files! for javascript and nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, eslint

**THIS is my problems**

Eslint cannot find the file's location?

This is the error!

[image]

Thank You in advance for the help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

**I was having this problem!**

Eslint cannot find the file's location because the path of the file is not fully defined, we must specify them in the configuration file.

**The reference exists and it works, the problem is that eslint cannot find it. I fix it as follows!**

**Unable to resolve the module path './Board'.** note that Board does not have an extension, that's the problem! We just need to specify eslint how to resolve the extensions and voila.

[image]

**I assume eslint installed and has problems integrating express node and react js projects**

**You can use the automatic configuration of eslint follow the steps and when it is installed configure your .eslint.json file add the description of *settings***

```
"settings": {
"import/resolver": {
  "node": {
    "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"],
    "moduleDirectory": ["node_modules", "src/"]
  }
}
```

}

> .eslintrc.json **the full file look like:**

```
    {
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": ["plugin:import/recommended", "plugin:react/recommended", "standard"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react"],
  "rules": {
    "semi": [2, "always"],
    "comma-dangle": [
      "error",
      {
        "arrays": "only-multiline",
        "objects": "only-multiline",
        "imports": "only-multiline",
        "exports": "only-multiline",
        "functions": "only-multiline"
      }
    ],
    "space-before-function-paren": 0,
    "spaced-comment": [
      "error",
      "never",
      {
        "line": {
          "markers": ["/"],
          "exceptions": ["-", "+"]
        },
        "block": {
          "markers": ["!", "-", "+"],
          "exceptions": ["*"],
          "balanced": true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"],
        "moduleDirectory": ["node_modules", "src/"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started